# Update table rows from jQuery

Tags: jquery-mobile, html-table

I'm working in building an Jquery mobile application, in that I had created a table, I need to update that table rows from DB.

This is my html...

```
  <table style="width:100%;" id="cart_table">
     <tr>
       <th>Item</th>
       <th>Qty</th>
       <th>Price</th>
       <th>Delete</th>
     </tr>       </table>
```

i called a showall() method to show all cart items in it when the cart button is clicked ..

```
 var row = ('<tr><td align="center"><a>'+cartitem1+'</a></td> <td align="center"><a>'+cart_qty+'</a></td> <td align="center"><a>'+cart_price+'</a></td><td align="center"><a><img src=""/></a></td></tr>');
      $("#cart_table").html(row.html());
```

This will be in for loop.I had put one row for sample ..
**Help me to update my row dynamically**

Answer (score 0):

I have changed this line

```
$("#cart_table").html(row.html());
```

to

```
$('#cart_table tr:last').after(row);
```

it works..

Thanks to [Luke Bennett](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery?rq=1)

Comment: or use `.append()`. `.html()` overwrites existing elements.

Comment: I know, you need to use `.append()`, `.prepend()`, `.after()`, `.before()` not [`.html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/).